# PyCharm gives code compatibility errors when inspection is unchecked

Tags: python, pycharm

So currently I'm getting:

`Python 3.5 does not support variable type annotations`

While using Python 3.6. Python 3.5 is installed on my system, but my Pytho interpreter is set to 3.6, and my Django console displays:

`Python 3.6.3 (default, Mar  7 2018, 09:30:28)`

Additionally, I've even turned off `Python -> Code` compatibility inspection in both my default and project specific settings.

Any ideas why I might still be getting the errors?

Comment: What interpreter is set in `File - Settings - Project Interpreter`?

Comment: The interpreter is 3.6.

Comment: If inspection is disabled, then such message is generated by annotator that determines your code as having Python 3.5 language level. That's why I asked about interpreter: language level is getting from the interpreter version. Please check that 3.5 is not used in the project and try to re-add 3.6.